# ruby/rails setup on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I created a new VM using virtualbox and ubuntu 14.  I then installed rvm using the following...

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

I'm still quite new to ubuntu/linux so I'm trying to get a handle on the terminal commands.  So, I think that I first did a

sudo su -

thinking that this would allow me to specify my password once and then remember it for each command.  But now I'm thinking that it instead changed me to the root account instead of my own?  The reason I suspect this is because when I first open a terminal under my account and type in ruby -v, I get..

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby
* ruby 1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

If I then do a sudo su - and follow it with ruby -v, I get

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

So, I'm not sure if I've done something wrong with the rvm installation or if there's some way to get my own account to use the same version of ruby as root?  Thanks.

Comment: So you have installed ruby *after* you ran `sudo su -`?

Comment: I did not install ruby separately.  But I think I installed rvm as root.  I found this link http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal but the suggestion to "Run command as a login shell" didn't work.  I get the same result.

Comment: I mean: did you run `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` *after* `sudo su -`?

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but I think so.

Comment: Then you've installed Ruby as root, I'll tell you how to fix that.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of.  do I need to uninstall it and install rvm under my main account?  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54950/discussion-between-geoff-swartz-and-tamer-shlash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you seem to have installed RVM as root. Doing that will make RVM and its rubies only "visible" to the root user. (Actually installing RVM for any user only makes it visible to that specific user AFAIK).

To fix that, first remove the root RVM installation, run `sudo su -` to become root (if you aren't already - to check what user you are you can run `whoami`). Then run the following:

```
rvm implode
```

This removes RVM altogether.

Next `exit` to become a normal user (again, check with `whoami`, if you're stuck just open a new terminal window) and run the RVM installation command:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

This should get you out of your problem.